# SQL track issues week on week (recursive function?)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, recursive-query

I have searched to the best of my ability but can't find an answer. I have a table where every week I record the IDs that are present in another table; this is so that I can track issues by ID. So if an ID is present a week, the issue was there. If the next week the ID is no longer present, the issue is resolved.

For example, this would be a sample data set:

create table #recursiveTest
(ID int,
 snapshotdate date
 )
insert into #recursiveTest
values 
(123456,'2014-09-01'),
(123456,'2014-09-08'),
(123456,'2014-09-15'),
(3123456,'2014-09-08'),
(3123456,'2014-09-15'),
(3123456,'2014-09-22'),
(6123456,'2014-09-29')

The view I am trying to get is:
on 9/1, I had one issue (only one ID with date 9/01)
on 9/8, I had 2 issues, of which one new (3123456) since it wasn't there last week
on 9/15, I have 2 issues still
on 9/22, I have 1 resolved issue (123456, which is no longer there) and still one issue
on 9/29, I have another resolved issue, plus a new issue that wasn't there before (6123456)

I am able (I think) to state what I want in pseudo code, but can't translate it into SQL code... I am using MS SQL server 2008.

Pseudo-code:
For each ID at each snapshot date:
  if there is no prior snapshot date, flag the issue as new
  Otherwise:
     left join with last week; if last week ID is null, then it's a new issue
     right join with last week; if THIS week ID is null, then it's resolved

I feel I need some sort of recursive function to go week by week and do the join then do an operation to find out whether there is a new or resolved issue, but I can't find how.

Any wizard out there who can help? I would be immensely grateful.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: You're rules don't make much sense to me.  If you're populating this table, if you haven't put in the new weeks data yet, it may flag something as "RESOLVED" when you just may not have pulled in that weeks data yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after..
To put in plain English.

I think you want to show all IDs and dates, but indicate which ones are new on the day they are new and which ones are closed on the day they are Resolved.  The problem I see with this is that resolved may return a false positive due to the fact that next weeks data may not be available yet and therefore would be null.  Thus the join and missing data both appear to be resolved when one isn't.

```
SELECT Case when RT2.SnapshotDate is null then 1 else 0 end as isNew, 
 case when RT3.snapshotDate is null then 1 else 0 end as isResolved,
 RT1.ID , RT1.SnapshotDate
FROM  recursiveTest RT1
LEFT JOIN recursiveTest Rt2
  on RT1.ID = RT2.ID 
 and RT1.Snapshotdate > Rt2.snapshotdate
LEFT JOIN RecursiveTest RT3
 on RT1.ID = RT3.ID
 and RT1.SnapshotDate < RT3.SnapshotDate
GROUP BY Case when RT2.SnapshotDate is null then 1 else 0 end, 
         case when RT3.snapshotDate is null then 1 else 0 end, RT1.ID , RT1.SnapshotDate
ORDER BY RT1.ID, Rt1.SnapshotDate
```

Returns:

```
isNew isResolved ID       SnapShotDate
    1   0        123456   01-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   0        123456   08-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   1        123456   15-SEP-14 00:00:00
    1   0        3123456  08-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   0        3123456  15-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   1        3123456  22-SEP-14 00:00:00
    1   1        6123456  29-SEP-14 00:00:00
```

Since we didn't care how many were before or how many were after, I used group by to limit possible cartiseans that could occur on given entries.

The problem I illustrated at the top is visible on 29-SEP-14 for ID 6123456.  Next week isn't visible so it's flagged as resolved.  But that's not likely the case.  The data you have presented provides no way to indicate this UNLESS we assume the largest date is always still open regardless of data set.  If so we can manage this via...

```
Select isNew, isResolved, ID, Snapshotdate FROM (
Select Case when RT2.SnapshotDate is null then 1 else 0 end as isNew, 
 case when RT1.snapshotDate = (Select max(snapshotDate) from recursiveTest) then 0 
       when RT3.snapshotDate is null then 1  else 0 end as isResolved,
 RT1.ID , RT1.SnapshotDate
from recursiveTest RT1
LEFT JOIN recursiveTest Rt2
  on RT1.ID = RT2.ID 
 and RT1.Snapshotdate > Rt2.snapshotdate
LEFT JOIN RecursiveTest RT3
 on RT1.ID = RT3.ID
 and RT1.SnapshotDate < RT3.SnapshotDate) 
GROUP BY isNew, isResolved, ID, Snapshotdate
order by ID, SnapshotDate
```

Which gives us:

```
  isNew isResolved ID       SnapShotDate
    1   0          123456   01-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   0          123456   08-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   1          123456   15-SEP-14 00:00:00
    1   0          3123456  08-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   0          3123456  15-SEP-14 00:00:00
    0   1          3123456  22-SEP-14 00:00:00
    1   0          6123456  29-SEP-14 00:00:00
```

or as a CTE (Common table expression) yielding the same results

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Case when RT2.SnapshotDate is null then 1 else 0 end as isNew, 
 case when RT1.snapshotDate = (Select max(snapshotDate) from recursiveTest) then 0 
       when RT3.snapshotDate is null then 1  else 0 end as isResolved,
 RT1.ID , RT1.SnapshotDate
FROM recursiveTest RT1
LEFT JOIN recursiveTest Rt2
  on RT1.ID = RT2.ID 
 and RT1.Snapshotdate > Rt2.snapshotdate
LEFT JOIN RecursiveTest RT3
 on RT1.ID = RT3.ID
 and RT1.SnapshotDate < RT3.SnapshotDate) 
SELECT isNew, isResolved, ID, SnapshotDate
FROM CTE
GROUP BY isNew, isResolved, ID, Snapshotdate
ORDER BY ID, SnapshotDate
```

Comment: Thank you xQbert SO much. This is exactly what I needed. And your latest assumption was right: the largest date is always still open regardless of the dataset. Really really appreciate your help.